# How can I write a VAWP link to a sendlog DE in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am attempting to write the emails VAWP link to a SendLog DE at the time a send. I have written the script below but it only writes to the first row of the SendLog. Please advise.

```
%%[ 
Set @JobID = jobid 
Set @VAWP = view_email_url 

set @rows = Lookuprows ("SendLog - ****_test","JobID",@JobID) 

set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 
if @rowCount > 0 then 
for @i = 1 to @rowCount do 

UpdateDE("SendLog - ****_test",1,"Jobid", @JobID, "VAWP Link", @VAWP) 

NEXT @i 


endif ]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

The SendLogging feature of Marketing Cloud automatically logs AMPscript-variables to the SendLog data extension if there is a corresponding column with that name. So if you rename your column from "VAWP Link" to "VAWP" this is the only line of your code that is still necessary:

```
%%[
  SET @VAWP = view_email_url
]%%
```

As mentioned in the comments, the AMPscript isn't even necessary, as you could also just rename the column to the exact name of the attribute "view_email_url" and it will be populated automatically then.

**Further reading:**

- [Unleash the power of Send Logging in Marketing Cloud](https://markus.codes/2017/07/20/unleash-the-power-of-send-logging-in-marketing-cloud)

Comment: You can also just include a field in the send log named `view_email_url` and it will automatically collect this for you without requiring you to define an AMPscript variable.

Comment: Yes sure, forgot to mention that while quickly replying to the question. I even mentioned it in my referenced blog article ;) Added it to the answer now, to be more complete. Thanks for pointing it out, Gregory!

Comment: @MarkusDang-formerlySlabina - if auto-send-logging is enabled, will this work for emails sent via the Transactional Messaging API too?

Comment: Some months ago I did check and at least back then emails sent via the Transactional Messaging API weren't even included in the send log data extension, so to my knowledge this unfortunately won't work.