# Capture View In Browser in Salesforce Tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-tracking

I am looking to capture the final post-send %%view_email_url%% url in my tracking. Is there a way to use AMPscript to capture this value for all sent email campaigns? Looking to be able to pass the web url so that we can use it for reporting.

Comment: You can for eg write the value of %%view_email_url%% in a Send Log DE or in another DE at send time - what exactly is the problem you are facing with this?

Comment: I am not seeing it in the out of the box tracking from Salesforce so wondering how I capture it as a custom field. You make it sound so easy! How do you write the value in a send log? @zuzannamj

Comment: You can view the solution outline in [this post here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/287704/how-can-i-write-a-vawp-link-to-a-sendlog-de-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud) on SFSE. Be aware, that VAWP links will break if/when the sendable data extension is overwritten or deleted. However, I don't understand your intention for "using it for reporting". Can you please provide more details in your question?